# Parameters to jump all the way through this assembly?

Tags: c, assembly

I am teaching myself how to understand assembly code, but need some help in ensuring whether I completely get what is going on. Here is the code, and my comments.

EDIT: What parameters will make this function "jump" all the way through?

We have the regular prologs in the beginning (not shown here). Then, we are storing %d %d which is in $0x804ae8d, as I looked at this value in GDB, and that is what is there.

```
 804989e:       ba 8d ae 04 08          mov    $0x804ae8d,%edx
 80498a3:       8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
 80498a6:       8d 4d f0                lea    -0x10(%ebp),%ecx
 80498a9:       89 4c 24 0c             mov    %ecx,0xc(%esp)
 80498ad:       8d 4d f4                lea    -0xc(%ebp),%ecx
 80498b0:       89 4c 24 08             mov    %ecx,0x8(%esp)
 80498b4:       89 54 24 04             mov    %edx,0x4(%esp)
 80498b8:       89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
```

I believe at this point (below) it is setting up two parameters basically to be taken in to the function. Here is is scanning those, and comparing the first parameter to see if it is greater than 1. If it is greater than 1, then it skips down to the next part.

```
 80498bb:       e8 b0 f3 ff ff          call   8048c70 <sscanf@plt>
 80498c0:       83 f8 01                cmp    $0x1,%eax
 80498c3:       7f 05                   jg     80498ca <level_2+0x32>
```

Here, it is adding the two parameters together and loading these in the register %eax. It is then comparing this new value in eax to see if it is now equal to 7100.

```
 80498ca:       8b 55 f4                mov    -0xc(%ebp),%edx
 80498cd:       8b 45 f0                mov    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
 80498d0:       01 d0                   add    %edx,%eax
 80498d2:       3d bc 1b 00 00          cmp    $0x1bbc,%eax
 80498d7:       74 07                   je     80498e0 <level_2+0x48>
```

I am not quite sure, however, what is happening here. I can see that it is perhaps taking the second parameter and loading that in the eax register. However, I'm not sure about and, test and the relevance of je here.

```
 80498e0:       8b 45 f4                mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
 80498e3:       8d 14 00                lea    (%eax,%eax,1),%edx
 80498e6:       8b 45 f4                mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
 80498e9:       21 d0                   and    %edx,%eax
 80498eb:       85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
 80498ed:       74 07                   je     80498f6 <level_2+0x5e>
```

And here, again, I'm not sure precisely what is being done. Although I suspect there is probably some comparison going on between the two parameters taken in.

```
 80498f6:       8b 55 f4                mov    -0xc(%ebp),%edx
 80498f9:       8b 45 f0                mov    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
 80498fc:       31 d0                   xor    %edx,%eax
 80498fe:       85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
 8049900:       7e 05                   jle    8049907 <level_2+0x6f>
```

Comment: `+0x???(%ebp)` are the function arguments, `-0x???(%ebp)` are the function local variables.

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking to understand the bottom two blocks, though.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure about the relevance of `test %eax,%eax` either. Obviously, `%eax` equals `%eax`, duh, then why test it? It would only make sense with `jz` or `jnz` after. Compilers optimize in mysterious ways.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TEST_(x86_instruction)

Comment: @Mat Right so are these just setting conditional flags? What is the point of it within the context of this function/program?

Comment: @Havenard Compilers issue some instructions not for their effects on the regular registers but for their effect on the FLAGS register. `test %eax,%eax` sets `Z` if `%eax` was `0` and `S` if `%eax` was `<0`. The `jle` that immediately follows means _jump if lesser than or equal to 0_.

Comment: Oh, thats why. So `test` set up some bits so that `je` work like `jnz`.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist With that in mind, what parameters would cause it to jump all the way through these blocks?

Comment: @marchon You read the 3rd-from-last block correctly. The 2nd-from-last block loads `-0xc(%ebp)` into `eax`, doubles it (equivalently, shifts it left by 1) while storing it in `edx` in a common if clever use of `LEA`, then ANDs it against the original value and checks that the value is 0. This amounts to the test "Are there consecutive one-bits in the binary representation of the `int` stored in `-0xc(%ebp)`".

Comment: Let `a = -0xc(%ebp)` and `b = -0x10(%ebp)`. It follows from the code that `a + b == 7100`, `(a & (a<<1)) == 0` and `(a ^ d) <= 0`.

Comment: The only way for `(a ^ d)` to be less than or equal to zero is if they differ in sign, or are identical.

Comment: `foo(char* s){int a, b; if((sscanf(s, "%d %d", &a, &b) > 1) && (a + b == 7100) && ((a & (a<<1)) == 0) && (a ^ d == 0)){/* bla */}}`

Comment: Given that `(gdb) p/t 7100` gives `$1 = 1101110111100` which has consecutive bits set, you cannot have `a == d` since it implies `a == 7100/2 == 0b110111011110`. Therefore precisely one of `a` and `b` is negative.

Comment: A pair of values that works is `a == 10900 (0b00000000000000000010101010010100), b == -3800 (0b11111111111111111111000100101000)`.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Sorry, above, did you mean (a ^ d) <= 0? There is no d in the code.

Comment: Yes, my bad `(a ^ b) <= 0`.